# Does a site has to be crawled to generate Usage Reports?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, reports, site-usage, 2019

I'm trying to get usage reports from my Enterprise Search Center (SharePoint 2019). 
Usage report is empty on ESC, but working on other sites.
The ESC isn't crawled, other sites are.
Is it the reason why I can't get those reports ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as usage reports are created by the Search Service you must crawl those sites.

Comment: Thanks you for confirming !